# How to add conditional props to style object in @emotion/react/Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion, css-in-js

[image]

I want to add props to control my css in emotion,but I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **wrap** it inside a `function` and handle your function param as `prop`.

```
const getMessageWrapperStyle = (props) => {
  css({
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: "20px",
    alignSelf: props.from_user === currentId ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
  });
};
```

And then use it like that:

```
css={getMessageWrapperStyle({ from_user: message.from_user })};
```